Problem when using SharedElementTransition with HorizontalPager in jetpack compose
I have a first screen with a list of images, and when I click on any image, it moves to another screen with HorizontalPager that displays all the images, and HorizontalPager is ready to start from the index of the image that was clicked (initialPage) and SharedElement is applied to this image. Now, if I change the image that SharedElement was applied to in the second screen (HorizontalPager Screen) by swiping left or right, SharedElement will not appear when I return to the first screen (which contains the list of images), but SharedElement will be applied to the image that was clicked on the first page. I want to apply SharedElemnt even if I change the image in the second screen (HorizontalPager). I hope that I was able to describe the problem correctly  Is there a solution to this problem?
